# @UniqueConstraints not working on @JoinTable

Tags: jpa, orm, playframework

I'm using Playframework 1.2.4 and PostgresSQL 9.1.2. I have the following entities: Recipe and RecipeItem. A Recipe has a set of RecipeItems. I've annotated the set of recipe items in the Recipe class as follows:

```
@Required
@MinSize(1)
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable( name = "RecipeItemForIngredients",
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "recipeId"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "recipeItemId"),
uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "uq_recipeItemPerRecipe",
columnNames = {"recipeId", "recipeItemId"}))
public Set<RecipeItem> items = Sets.newHashSet();
```

But when I check the PgAdmin to see if the constraint has been applied to the RecipeItemForIngredients table I cannot find it. This is what PgAdmin shows.

```
CREATE TABLE recipeitemforingredients
(
  recipeid bigint NOT NULL,
  recipeitemid bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT recipeitemforingredients_pkey PRIMARY KEY (recipeid, recipeitemid),
  CONSTRAINT fk5ac547a883708db FOREIGN KEY (recipeid)
      REFERENCES recipe (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk5ac547ad6e1da8f FOREIGN KEY (recipeitemid)
      REFERENCES "recipe$recipeitem" (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT recipeitemforingredients_recipeitemid_key UNIQUE (recipeitemid)
)
```

Does anyone have an idea why this could be happening? Maybe this annotation is not supported by the ORM used by Playframework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This constraint doesn't make much sense, and you have a stronger constraint by default anyway:

```
CONSTRAINT recipeitemforingredients_recipeitemid_key UNIQUE (recipeitemid)
```

If `recipeItemId` is unique, then of course, the tuple `(recipeId, recipeItemId)` is also unique.

Moreover, since the PK of the table is `(recipeId, recipeItemId)`, the constraint is already applied by the PK constraint.

Comment: OK although a recipe cannot repeat an ingredient thanks to the primary key. I want to know why it decides to use the primary key instead of just using the unique named constraint

Comment: I don't know. Maybe it's smart enough to detect duplicate or unnecessary constraints.